# Asterisk channel variable set before dialplan executes?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

The backstory is that I am trying to debug an issue I am having with FreePBX currently. The channel variable `REC_STATUS` is set to `RECORDING` when it shouldn't be.

After quite a bit of troubleshooting and no sign of anything in the dialplan that could be causing this, I decided to insert a `NoOp(${REC_STATUS})` as the first line of dialplan code to be executed for a new incoming call. Guess what? `REC_STATUS` is already set to `RECORDING` as of the first line of dialplan execution for these new calls.

My question is this: how is this channel variable already set before the dialplan starts executing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there's a way to set global variables in Asterisk, and when you go to request a variable for a channel, the global value will be shown if the variable has not been set otherwise on the channel.

I resolved my issue by executing the following on the dialplan once:

`Set(GLOBAL(REC_STATUS)=)`

Using any of these options did not work:

```
Set(REC_STATUS=)
Set(_REC_STATUS=)
Set(__REC_STATUS=)
```